# How to print contents of google scripts logging console into spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, console.log

Is there a way to print the contents of google scripts logging console (tools-> script editor -> view -> logs) into the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var stringToWrite = Logger.getLog();
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange("A1").setValue(stringToWrite);
```

See the documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger